# Is there a way to start a local Java IBM Liberty Server from terminal?

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere-liberty

Is there a way to start/stop a Liberty Server from terminal/command line?
I tried some commands but no luck so far

[image: Eclipse IDE view]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are a few ways to start Liberty on the command line.

## A) Directly with server script

Locate your Liberty install (`$WLP_INSTALL_DIR`), the sever can be started in the background using the command `$WLP_INSTALL_DIR/bin/server start <serverName>`.

For example: `/path/to/wlp/bin/server start myServer`

For doc on starting/stopping the server, see the [Server Commands](https://openliberty.io/docs/ref/command/) reference.

## B) Using the Liberty Maven plugin

If your project uses Maven, there is a Liberty plugin that provides some very helpful tasks, such as:

- `mvn liberty:start` starts a Liberty server in the background
- `mvn liberty:run` starts a Liberty server in the foreground
- `mvn liberty:dev` starts a Liberty server in "dev mode" where code/config changes are automatically updated without needing to restart your server

To learn more about the Liberty Maven plugin, check out the [Liberty guide here](https://openliberty.io/guides/getting-started.html)